# How do I have to modify the weather-widget to work as JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just programming my first website and I want to implement the weather widget from weatherwidget.io to my website. 
This is the code you get from their website:

```
<a class="weatherwidget-io" href="https://forecast7.com/de/48d109d79/***/" data-label_1="***" data-label_2="WEATHER" data-days="0" data-theme="dark" >*** WEATHER</a>
<script>    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','weatherwidget-io-js');</script>
```

If I paste this in my HTML it works just fine.
Next I tried to move the script part to an external file called `Mirror.js`.

```
<script src="Mirror.js"></script>
```

If I now paste the part that used to be between `<script>` and `</script>` in the `Mirror.js` file, it doesn't work anymore. As I didn't write the original code, I don't know  what went wrong and how I have to modify the code in order for it to work.

Comment: You need to leave the HTML part in your HTML file and put just the part between the script tags (the actual js) in your Mirror.js file.  It's erroring cuz you are putting HTML into a js file.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: The snippet that you tried to move to an external script only checks whether weatherwidget-io's script already has been loaded, and if not, loads it asynchronously. Putting this snippet in a external script defeats the entire point. You should rather use `<script src="https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js" async></script>`.